# How do I combine multiple formulas into one cell? remove duplicates and keep latest date in google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a code that filters data by 2 dates. I also want it to remove any duplicates and keep the latest date.

This is what I have that gets the data. I need to know how to add `DUPLICATE` to the formula. Then keep the latest date.

```
=QUERY(All!A:Z, "Select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H where toDate(E) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and toDate(E) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"
```

UPDATE: 
 QUERY(All!A:Z, "select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H 
                 where toDate(E) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                   and toDate(E) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
                 order by (I) desc", (FILTER(A:Z,TRUE)
                  ))

Comment: Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ/edit?usp=sharing                               I have an importrange code that imports data, then within the same sheet I have another formula that is looking for true or false values. How do I make the formula only show True values for the query and the other formula without making another sheet?

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works for you:

```
=QUERY(All!A:Z, "select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H 
                 where toDate(E) >= date '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                   and toDate(E) <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                 order by toDate(E) desc 
                 limit 1", 0)
```

Comment: I want to order by date, but remove duplicates of project name and keep only keep the latest project  submitted. Do you use max? Thank you